# unable to see toast inside oncreate

Tags: android, multithreading

```
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Security extends MainActivity {

    Socket sock,sock1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.security);

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
            try{
                sock=new Socket(ip,port1);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                String a=br.readLine();
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter the result of operation for no "+a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

        }).start();

    }


}
```

Not able to view toast when Security started. I dont know why? it is like that it should be wit in oncliklistener.?

Comment: Only Toast messages from the `MainThread` for the above use an `ASyncTask` not a raw `Thread`. This gives you access to `onPostExecute` which is exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter the result of operation for no "+a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: okay.but i also need to run socket code.and it is only applicable with raw Thread.then what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can only show toasts in the main UI thread.

If you need to do things on the UI thread from a background thread, have a look at `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: okay.but i also need to run socket code.and it is only applicable with raw Thread.then what to do